# Make all WordPress URLs lowercase

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to to get all my WordPress urls to be lowercase, but the following code doesn't seem to be working...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteMap tolower int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${tolower:$1} [R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I need to do this because a client I just converted from Drupal to WordPress has a bunch of old URLs that have capitalization in them, but the records were all in lowercase. The old plugin converted the URLs to lowercase, but the new redirection plugin doesn't. Now /Boston isn't going to /boston anymore, it just gets a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module `mod_speling` for PHP (you need to load it first) and the `CheckCaseOnly on|off` option in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: how to load it? - I am hosting my site on godaddy